# multi curl does not work asynch with different proxies

Tags: php, curl, hhvm

So I am using [parallelcurl](https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl) lib in this code, but I have tried other wrappers and the result is pretty much the same, which is, if I specify a proxy
the requests are not handled asynchronously but sequentially, as soon as I do not specify the proxy option it works like it should in async...why? I have to add that I am using hhvm but does not seem to be a problem with it...

```
$timeout = 2;
$opt_arr = array(
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => $timeout
);
$parallelcurl = new ParallelCurl(200, $opt_arr);
foreach($proxies as $proxy){
    $opt_arr[CURLOPT_PROXY] = $proxy;
    $parallelcurl->setOptions($opt_arr);
    $parallelcurl->startRequest($url, 'callback_p', array('proxy'=> $proxy));
}

$parallelcurl->finishAllRequests();
```

Comment: I tried [rolling curl](https://github.com/chuyskywalker/rolling-curl), I can use up to 17 threads and results are consistent, then:
18 threads ~30% success rate, 
19 threads ~10%, 
20+ threads 0% success rate/inconsistent.  
If instead of using `_PROXY` I use `_URL` the urls are fetched correctly for hundres of threads, tested also with a proxy checker made in python, and can succesfully check proxies with hundres of threads (100-300), so the bandwidth of the server is not a problem...it must be a problem with how curl_multi handles the CURLOPT_PROXY option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is not in php or curl, but in the test url, I totally had tunnel vision into this and it never occurred to me since I was testing them against google, and so it seems like google hard cap requests at 17 threads, after that it throws out denies